# Why does Apple Music split up albums?

Tags: music.app

I have Loscil's "Endless Falls", and Music thinks it's three albums. I've checked the metadata, and they all have the right artist, album, and track x/8. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Because the metadata doesn't match.  That's the only reason why.

Comment: Select all of them and CMD-I to view metadata. Find the different metadata and make it the same.

Comment: But my iPhone and iPad recognize them as the same albums. I will check again though.

Comment: I just had a similar case (1 album, 2 discs) and I don't know what the difference was, but the app showed the same information under "album artist" (with no extra spaces or the likes) for both discs.  Selecting them all and cutting out the album artist united the album and pasting the album artist back in kept it the right way.

Comment: To continue my comment above:  today I launched Music again and the 1 album has been split to 2 again.  So what is changing the metadata, if not the Music.app itself?  (@Marc @At0mic)

Comment: @MarcWilson "One time, I had a split album where none of the metadata were 'mixed.' In that case, it was fixed by changing the compilation check box, clicking OK, then opening Cmd-I again and changing it back." This was the solution. So yes, the meta data were the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be another cause, but here is a way worked for me:

1. In the Songs view, sort by the album or artist or anything that puts
   the tracks of the "two" albums together.
2. Select at least one track from each album (multiple selection).
3. Cmd-I (Get Info)
4. If there is any metadata shown faintly as "Mixed," change it to whatever it should be (other than comments, or things like track, disk, that should be different).
5. If artist is supposed to be different, don't change that.  Instead, select (turn on) the compilation checkbox.
6. Click OK and see whether they have merged.

One time, I had a split album where **none** of the metadata were "mixed."  In that case, it was fixed by changing the compilation check box, clicking OK, then opening Cmd-I again and changing it back.

Comment: The compilation trick works great, IMO that’s the best part of this answer